# Configure method isn't being called

Tags: tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas

So I want to detect changes in the size of the window, and I was told that you can override the Configure method, so I did that, but when I try changing the window it doesn't seem to get called.

```
class ChangingCanvas(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self,parent,**kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self,parent,**kwargs)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)
        self.height = self.winfo_height()
        self.width = self.winfo_width()

    def resize(self,event):
        self.width = event.width
        self.height = event.height
        print(self.width, self.height,self.winfo_height())
        self.config(width=self.width, height = self.height)

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.canvas = ChangingCanvas(self,highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.grid(column=1,row=1)
```

Nothing is printing, so I know it doesn't go inside the resize method. What's happening?

Answer (score 0):

The method isn't being called because your canvas never changes size. Give your canvas a distinct color and you'll see that it doesn't resize. This is because a) you haven't configured the application to grow and shrink when the main window grows and shrinks, and b) you haven't configured the canvas to grow and shrink with the application grows and shrinks.

Comment: So how do I make the canvas resize with the main window?

Comment: There are lots of questions and answers related to that topic. If you are using `grid` you need to use the `sticky` option, and you must give your rows and columns weights so that extra space is allocated to them.